# newcommandx in tabularx

Tags: latex, tabular, xargs, xelatex

I would like to make `\newcommandx` and `\renewcommandx` work in `tabularx`.

In fact, when I call them inside the `tabularx` environment, they are ignored.

Does anyone has a solution ?

Here's a minimal example :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

%
%First try without tabularx
%
\newcommandx{\test}[1][1=]{
1
\renewcommandx{\test}[1][1=]{2}}

%Return : 1, 2 : GOOD
\test, \test



%
%Second try with tabularx
%
\let\test\relax
\newcommandx{\test}[1][1=]{
1
\renewcommandx{\test}[1][1=]{2}}

%Return : 1,1 : BAD (expected 1,2)
\begin{tabularx}{0.1\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \test & \test \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please make a [mre] that will show how `\newcommandx` etc are defined or from which package they come and also explain why you want to change definition inside the table. This feels like an XY-problem to me.

Comment: Ok, just posted it !

Comment: Use a counter for something like that

Comment: I put 1 and 2 for the minimal. In my real TeX this isn't 1 or 2 but other things a lot more complicated.